# Не работает маска ввода если заходить с телефона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Маска ввода от JQ пишет невидимки какие-то если с телефона можете посмотреть тут [myeveryday.ru](http://myeveryday.ru) , с компа все нормально. Там плюсик, если нажать выезжает форма с добавлением задачи

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.mask.definitions['2']='[0-2]';
    $.mask.definitions['3']='[0-3]';
    $.mask.definitions['5']='[0-5]';
    $.mask.definitions['9']='[0-9]';
    $(".quick_time").mask("23:59");
});
```

Comment: Некорректно конечно работает, потому что 17:00 я поставить не могу, но работает все

Comment: ну а я вообще ничего не могу поставить с телефона. в чем дело то? на компе все идеально работает

Comment: Тяжело понять так, потому что я открыл все, и все работает с iPhone 6 - это точно

Comment: ок спасибо, может мне просто телефон на помойку надо выкинуть=)))